# Windows Movie Maker not adding audio from wma; can use different program all together

Tags: windows, audio, video, windows-movie-maker

What's the simplest way to do this?

I've got several audio files in the `.amr` format. I want to add them to a Power Point Presentation and have a video of it (so the audio would play in time of seeing the right slides). I want this video to be on YouTube or a similar site.

I tried using Windows Movie Creator. It said amr wasn't supported so I converted to wma. What do you know, it still says wma isn't supported. I don't know why since the documentation says that wma is supported; I go to home -> add videos and photos -> choose all file types -> chose the wma and get
[image: screen shot]

What's the easiest way to fix this? 1) fix the problem with Movie Maker not adding wma 2) use a different program all together

Comment: How did you convert from `amr` to `wma`?

Comment: @DavidPostill using this website http://media.io/

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a difficult problem.

Comment: Downvotes are anonymous (and it wasn't me) so if they don't leave a comment you won't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Avidemux is great:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/avidemux/

> Avidemux is a free video editor designed for simple cutting, filtering and encoding tasks. It supports many file types, including AVI, DVD compatible MPEG files, MP4 and ASF, using a variety of codecs. Tasks can be automated using projects, job queue and powerful scripting capabilities.

There is a video tutorial for your question:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rFAKH3V5p8

It's simple: Open the video you want to edit and select the menu "audio -> select Track". On Track one, in the first combo box, you can select the option "... Add Audio Track" to add your own audio track for this video file. 
Afterwards, you can select the video and audio output formats on the left side of the main window. 
To export the combined video/audio file, use: "File -> Save".

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself.

Comment: For some reason Avidemux has the same problem and says it can't load the file.

Comment: Did you try the wma file and the original amr file?